# Building a fingerprint-based system

Tags: authentication, fingerprint, biometrics

So I've got a project at work which involves biometric authentication. From my reading I understand this is a giant mess with lots of vendor-specific methods of doing things, but I have looked in to a few solutions. I managed to get authentication against Windows user accounts working through the Windows Biometric Framework, but this is far from ideal. Really I'd like to either retrieve the raw image of the print so I can process it myself using openAFIS or a similar library, or get some sort of unique key or other hash value which could be used to identify the user. I understand this is possible via WBF and WinBioCaptureSample but I haven't played with it yet. I'm happy to work in almost any programming language, although preferably C# or Java, and preferably not C++ since I'm far from an expert (building an interop for WBF nearly killed me!)

Really I'd like to hear from anyone who's ever implemented a system involving fingerprints and how you went about it! I'm trying to avoid expensive SDKs (and most of them are very expensive) but if there's a cheap one out there that works I'd be happy to pay for it.

As far as hardware, I have access to two sensors right now both based on the Authentec AES1610, although the hardware for the final project hasn't been acquired yet and can therefore be anything - whatever's easiest! I'm assuming contacting Authentec for details on their SDK would be futile since their developer page says they're no longer offering it :/

So... thoughts?